# Implement the removeProperty function

Tags: javascript

Using only JS Implement the removeProperty function which takes an object and property name, and does the following:

If the object obj has a property prop, the function removes the property from the object and returns true; in all other cases it returns false.

```
    function removeProperty(obj, prop) {

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')) { 
    delete obj['prop'];
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is returning:

```
      Property removed: Wrong answer 
  Correct return value: Wrong answer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a string  not variable .try like this pass the variable of `prop` remove the `'`

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Could I just ask - Why does delete obj[prop] work while delete obj.prop not work?

Comment: @Wally `prop` is variable, not the real key name of the obj .`obj.prop` is same as like `obj = {prop:'something'}` so `prop` act as key name string not variable  . if you are use like `obj[prop]` .That variable name assign to object key .eg `var prop = 'a'; var obj ={a:'something'} ` .its called object dynamic key call .[refer this document](https://usefulangle.com/post/196/javascript-object-dynamic-key)

Comment: Oddly this is a little hard to write concisely - but i did some rresearch on top of your answer and understand how to use it now - thanks for the reply :)